# <ul> Style property works in FireFox but not in IE

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list and I have set the style property 'none' so that the circles are not displayed before the list items. It works fine in Firefox but in IE still those circle are present. So can any one help me how to it in IE also?

I have written like:

```
            <ul type="none" style="text-align:left;">  
            <li><a href="a.aspx">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="b.aspx">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="c.aspx">Item3</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use CSS instead of inline coding?

Comment: Off topic but I think you should see this: http://bit.ly/9P2m77

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this ,

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
.....

</ul>
```